# I get a link with params and need to open that page only, nothing else. I have the page ready. Vue Js

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

The link would be like this: https://server/fleet/20210705001. How can I display this page when someone enters this link in address bar from anywhere. No authentication, no security, just the page needs to be opened. I have this working in local but couldn't make it work in production. Can someone help me?
This is my index.js in router folder

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import Fleet from '../views/Fleet.vue'


const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/feedback/:id',
    name: 'Fleet',
    component: Fleet,
  },
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
 next();
});

export default router
```

And this is my main.js

```
 import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'

//import './axios-settings'

//Vue.config.productionTip = true;

createApp(App).use(router).mount('#app')
```

Can someone guide me?

Answer (score 0):

`router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {next({ name: 'Fleet' });});`

Comment: Hi Sefa! It worked when I commented the whole navigation guard thing. I tried your suggestion to see if that works but it didn't.  Anyway thank you for the suggestion.